# { errorCode: 'INVALID_REQUEST_BODY', when trying to send envelope

Tags: javascript, node.js, docusignapi

I am trying to send an envelope using a template. I use form data to capture all the needed fields for this call. I created the object below, then append to add values from user. then send through JSON.stringify before sending to http post. For some reason still getting error  INVALID_BODY_REQUEST

```
var data = [

{        
  "documents": [
    {

      "documentId": "27730895",
      "fileExtension": "pdf",
      "name": "Top Level Staging",
      "order": "1"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Please Sign document",
  "status": "sent",
  "templateId": "4fda9b93-9c82-4f23-bd06-67f9b35f0183",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "",
      "name": "",
      "roleName": "Client",
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "documentId": "27730895",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "tabLabel": "cPackage",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "documentId": "27730895",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "tabLabel": "sDate",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "documentId": "27730895",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "tabLabel": "pAddress",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "documentId": "27730895",
            "pageNumber": "2",
            "tabLabel": "rAmount",
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}];
```

I create this and append it using user data submitted in from a form. Here is how i append the the object.

```
  var  contract_data = {    

         cEmail:req.body.cEmail,
         FullName:req.body.cName,
         pAddress:req.body.pAddress,
         cAmount:req.body.cAmount,
         rAmount:req.body.rAmount,
         dCompleted:req.body.dCompleted,
         cDate:req.body.cDate, 
         cPackage:req.body.cPackage

    };

 /data[0].templateRoles[1] = contract_data.cEmail;
    data[0].templateRoles[2] = contract_data.FullName;
    data[0].templateRoles[0].tabs.textTabs[0].value = contract_data.cPackage;
    data[0].templateRoles[0].tabs.textTabs[1].value = contract_data.dCompleted;
    data[0].templateRoles[0].tabs.textTabs[2].value = contract_data.pAdress;
    data[0].templateRoles[0].tabs.textTabs[3].value = contract_data.rAmount;
```

I then send that data array through JSON.stringify() like so

```
var body = JSON.stringify(data)
```

send to post with request

```
 request({
        headers:{"X-DocuSign-Authentication":creds},
        url: "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/3465212/envelopes",
        json: true,   // <--Very important!!!
        body: body,
        method: "POST",

    }, function (error, response, body){
            console.log(response.body);
        });
```

Comment: are cPackage, sDate, pAddress and rAmount tabs in the template -  4fda9b93-9c82-4f23-bd06-67f9b35f0183? If you want to send envelope using template then why are you adding document also?

Comment: Yes these are on the template copied the object from the API explorer after testing. I did take off the document and still no go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of request body should not be an array.

Change it as follows. Removed the `[]`

```
var data = 
   {        
     "documents": [
       {
          //Removed document properties for brevity
       }
     ],
     "emailSubject": "Please Sign document",
     "status": "sent",
     "templateId": "4fda9b93-9c82-4f23-bd06-67f9b35f0183",
     "templateRoles": [
       {
          //Removed template roles for brevity             
       }
     ]
   };
```

An then update the template roles as follows. Use `data` instead of `data[0]` as it is no longer an array.

```
var tRole = data.templateRoles[0];
tRole.email = contract_data.cEmail;
tRole.name = contract_data.FullName;
tRole.tabs.textTabs[0].value = contract_data.cPackage;
tRole.tabs.textTabs[1].value = contract_data.dCompleted;
tRole.tabs.textTabs[2].value = contract_data.pAdress;
tRole.tabs.textTabs[3].value = contract_data.rAmount;
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case but when I remove the outer brackets i get the failed to lookup error. and when i add back the program makes it all the way to the API call and renders the page back  instead of bombing

Comment: Where are you getting the failed to lookup error? Did you update the code where you are substituting the values from the request body?

Comment: update code where substituting values and it went back to { errorCode: 'INVALID_REQUEST_BODY',

Comment: try removing the statement `var body = JSON.stringify(data) ` use data directly in your request. Since you are already specifying the `content-type` as json,  you are not required to stringify the request body.

Comment: With some tweaking I got it working. You definitely steered the ship on this one